# Create cloudformation resource multiply times

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I've just moved to cloud formation and I am starting with creating ECR repositories for docker,
I need all repositories to have the same properties except the repository name.

Since this is micro-services I will need at least 40 repo's so I want to create a stack that will create the repo's for me in a loop, and just change the name.

I started looking at nested stacks and this is what I got so far:

**ecr-root.yaml:**

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: ECR docekr repository
Parameters:
  ECRRepositoryName:
    Description: ECR repository name
    Type:  AWS::ECR::Repository::RepositoryName
Resources:
  ECRStack:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: https://cloudformation.s3.amazonaws.com/ecr-stack.yaml
      TimeoutInMinutes: '20'
      Parameters:
        ECRRepositoryName: !GetAtt 'ECRStack.Outputs.ECRRepositoryName'
```

**And ecr-stack.yaml:**

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Parameters:
  ECRRepositoryName:
    Description: ECR repository name
    Default: panpwr-mysql-base
    Type: String

Resources:
    MyRepository:
    Type: AWS::ECR::Repository
    Properties:
      RepositoryName: 
        ref: ECRRepositoryName
      RepositoryPolicyText:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          -
            Sid: AllowPushPull
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS:
                - "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/Bob"
                - "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/Alice"
            Action:
              - "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer"
              - "ecr:BatchGetImage"
              - "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability"
              - "ecr:PutImage"
              - "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload"
              - "ecr:UploadLayerPart"
              - "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload"

RepositoryNameExport:
    Description: RepositoryName for export
    Value:
      Ref: ECRRepositoryName
    Export:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: "ECRRepositoryName"
```

Everything is working fine,
But when I'm running the stack it asks me for the repository name I want to give it, and it creates one repository.
And then I can have as many stacks that I want with a different name but that is not my purpose.

How do I get it all in one stack that creates as many repositories that I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to loop through a given list of parameters. Looping is not possible in a CloudFormation template. Few things you can try

1. You could programmatically generate a template. The [troposphere](https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere) Python library provides a nice abstraction to generate templates.
2. [Write custom resource backed by AWS lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html). You can handle your custom logic in the AWS lambda function .
3. The AWS Cloud Development Kit (AWS CDK) is an open-source software development framework to define cloud infrastructure in code and provision it through AWS CloudFormation. Use [AWS CDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk) to write custom script for your usecase.